# Photo Uploaded is inverted - Android App

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

So we're trying to implement an upload image feature in our Android App.
In our registration page, there is an upload button and once pressed, it should redirect to the image gallery and once an image is selected, it should be displayed in the ImageView placed.

Here's an excerpt of the code we're trying to work on. 
The issue is, for some images it is correctly displayed but for some, it is either rotated 90 degrees to the right or 180 degrees.

What could be the issue?

```
     public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mName = "";
    private String mUsername = "";
    private String mPassword = "";
    private String mCompany = "";
    private String mContact = "";

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    ImageView imageView;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Intent recvdIntent = getIntent();

        mName = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("NAME");
        mUsername = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        mPassword = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD");
        mCompany = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("COMPANY");
        mContact = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("CONTACT");

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        submitUserData();
                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Category.class);
                        return;
                    }
                }
        );

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openGallery();
                    }
                });
        return;
    }


    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotate(bitmap, 90);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotate(bitmap, 180);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotate(bitmap, 270);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                return flip(bitmap, true, false);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                return flip(bitmap, false, true);

            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degrees);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }


    private void submitUserData() {
        EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        EditText edtCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_company);
        EditText edtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contact);
        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        TaraApp2 app = (TaraApp2) getApplication();
        app.saveUserData(edtName.getText().toString(),edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                edtPassword.getText().toString(),
                edtCompany.getText().toString(),
                edtContact.getText().toString() );

        finish();
        return;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the version of your android device ?

Comment: Why posting all that modifyorientation stuff? You are not using it. It distracts from your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = scaleImage(this,selectedImageUri);


public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, Uri photoUri) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
        is.close();

        int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
        int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);

        if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
        } else {
            rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
            rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
        }

        Bitmap srcBitmap;
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
        if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
            float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight) / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
            float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);

            // Create the bitmap from file
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } else {
            srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        }
        is.close();

        /*
         * if the orientation is not 0 (or -1, which means we don't know), we
         * have to do a rotation.
         */
        if (orientation > 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, srcBitmap.getWidth(),
                    srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (type.equals("image/png")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
            srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
```

for getting url of the image use this

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
        String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
        } else {
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm getting an error on the Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData(); line. It cannot resolve the method getData(). For the Bitmap bitmap = scaleImage(this,selectedImageUri); line, it has an unhandled exception error (java.io)

Answer (score 0):

```
For accessing picture from your gallery you can use the croperino library. 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4374

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Croperino.prepareGallery(MainActivity.this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {   
        case CroperinoConfig.REQUEST_PICK_FILE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                CroperinoFileUtil.newGalleryFile(data, MainActivity.this);
                Croperino.runCropImage(CroperinoFileUtil.getmFileTemp(), 
                MainActivity.this, true, 1, 1, 0, 0);
            }
            break;
        case CroperinoConfig.REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri i = Uri.fromFile(CroperinoFileUtil.getmFileTemp());
                ivMain.setImageURI(i);
                //Do saving / uploading of photo method here.
                //The image file can always be retrieved via 
                CroperinoFileUtil.getmFileTemp()
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```